# Nodejs Websockets User Active State with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a NodeJS backend with Express and WS, and is a simple messenger-like chat app. You login, then you chat. But I want to add a feature on top of it. If a user is already logged and ACTIVE (socket connection exists, not broken) I want it's `activeStatus : active` in database. So that if he tries to login from a different browser, if his activeStatus is `active`, he won't be able to connect.

How is this achievable? I cannot understand how am I supposed to link a websocket connection to a specific ID in database, and when connection is on, update db, and when connection drops, update it to that ID again.

Answer (score 2):

Just set a unique parameter for `WebSocket` instance in `wss.on('connection',...)` and use it later to identify the user. Also, if you aren't able to link websocket connection to a specified user, how does your authentication work? It seems like anyone can connect to your server, if it can't differentiate between users.

Comment: How exactly would I do that in the big picture? Sorry, I'm new to WS. Also, auth is email & pass based.